# selecting dropdown value need to get both the dropdown values in listbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

1. I have a text Box customername
2. Dropdown Containing Languages like (Arabic,Europe,French(candian),French(Europe),English,English(Asia),English(Hispanic), India,Europe,English,English(Asia),English(Hispanic),Dutch).
3. When I enter a customer name in textbox and select drop down value as English(Asia) then in listbox customer name with English(Asia) will be added. 
   Example:  John- English(Asia)
4. But now when I select French(Canadian) in drop downand click on add I need to get both the french(canadian) And French(Europe) in the listbox with same Customer Name. It Shouldbe Like John- French(candian) John- French(Europe).
5. If there is already french(Europe) in the list box then if I select French(canadian) And click on add button then only french(canadian) should be added with customer name.

```js
function UpdateAlternateCustomerNamesList(action) {
  if (action == "Add") {
    if ((!(document.getElementById("txtAltLangAccName").value.trim().length > 0)) && (!(document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").selectedIndex > 0))) {
      alert("Alternate-Language Customer Name cannot be empty and please select a Language");
    } else if (!(document.getElementById("txtAltLangAccName").value.trim().length > 0)) {
      alert("Alternate-Language Customer Name cannot be empty");
    } else if (!(document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").selectedIndex > 0)) {
      alert("Please select a Language");
    } else {
      var sNewLIText = document.getElementById("txtAltLangAccName").value.trim() + " - " + document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").item(document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").selectedIndex).text;
      var sNewLIValue = document.getElementById("txtAltLangAccName").value.trim() + " - " + document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").item(document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").selectedIndex).value;
      var lstAltCustNames = document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames");
      var count = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < lstAltCustNames.options.length; i++) {
        var lstAltCustName = lstAltCustNames[i].text.toString();
        var lstAltCust = lstAltCustName.split(' - ');
        if (lstAltCust[1] == (document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").item(document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").selectedIndex).text)) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      if (count == 0) {
        var nListItem = document.createElement("Option");
        nListItem.text = sNewLIText;
        nListItem.value = sNewLIValue;
        document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options.add(nListItem);
        document.getElementById("hdnAltLangCustNamesColl").value = sNewLIText + "[@#$$#@]" + sNewLIValue + "[@#$$#@]" + document.getElementById("hdnAltLangCustNamesColl").value;

        var sLanguage = document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").item(document.getElementById("ddlLangauge").selectedIndex).text;
        if (($("#hdnIsCNWCustomer").val() == "1") && (sLanguage == "English" || sLanguage == "French (Canadian)"))
          alert("Please check Colines");

        document.getElementById("txtAltLangAccName").value = "";
        if ($("#lstAltCustNames").children().length > 0) {
          SortListbox('#lstAltCustNames');
        }
      } else {
        alert("An alternate name with the same language already exists for this customer.");
      }
    }
  } else {

    if (document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").selectedIndex > -1) {

      var sAltCustName = document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options[document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").selectedIndex].text;
      var sLanguage = sAltCustName.substring(sAltCustName.lastIndexOf("-") + 2, sAltCustName.length);
      if (($("#hdnIsCNWCustomer").val() == "1") && (sLanguage == "English" || sLanguage == "French (Canadian)"))
        alert("Please check Colines");

      document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options.remove(document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").selectedIndex);

      var iNoOfAltLangCustNames = document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").length;
      if (iNoOfAltLangCustNames > 0) {
        var sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames = "";
        for (var iIndex = 0; iIndex <= iNoOfAltLangCustNames - 1; iIndex++) {
          if (sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames == "") {
            sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames = document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options[iIndex].text + "[@#$$#@]" + document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options[iIndex].value;
          } else {
            sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames = document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options[iIndex].text + "[@#$$#@]" + document.getElementById("lstAltCustNames").options[iIndex].value + "[@#$$#@]" + sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames;
          }
        }
        document.getElementById('hdnAltLangCustNamesColl').value = "";
        document.getElementById('hdnAltLangCustNamesColl').value = sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames;
      } else {
        //                        document.getElementById('hdnAltLangCustNamesColl').value = sUpdatedListOfAltLangCustNames;
        document.getElementById('hdnAltLangCustNamesColl').value = "";
      }
      if ($("#lstAltCustNames").children().length > 0) {
        SortListbox('#lstAltCustNames');
      }
    } else
      alert("Please select Alternate-Language Customer Name");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<td class="label-left" align="left" rowspan="2">Alternate-Language Customer Name(s)</td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAltLangAccName" runat="server" CssClass="input-text" MaxLength="360" Width="480px"></asp:TextBox>
<td class="label-left" align="left">Language</td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLangauge" runat="server" CssClass="input-text" Width="150px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ListBox ID="lstAltCustNames" runat="server" CssClass="input-text" Width="600px" Rows="4" SelectionMode="Single" EnableViewState="true"></asp:ListBox>
<input type="hidden" id="hdnAltLangCustNamesColl" name="hdnAltCustNamesColl" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAltCustAdd" CssClass="button" Width="64px" Text="Add" CausesValidation="False" onclick="return UpdateAlternateCustomerNamesList('Add');" runat="server"></asp:Button>

<asp:Button ID="btnAltCustRemove" CssClass="button" Width="64px" Text="Remove" CausesValidation="False" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

1. When I select  French(Canadian) in drop down and click on add I need to get both the french(Canadian) And French(Europe) in the listbox with same Customer Name.
   It should be Like 
   John- French(Canadian)
   John- French(Europe).
2. If there is already french(Europe) in the list box then if I select French(Canadian) And click on add button then only french(Canadian) should be added with customer name(because already french(Europe) is already added).

Comment: ohh buddy, this is really difficult to read. please go though [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When i select A dropdown value(French(Canadian)) i need to get both the french(Canadian) and French(Europe) data and bind it in the listbox .
French(Canadian)====>Dropdown Selected value
Output===>French(Canadian)
          French(Europe)